# Proc report is exporting file size larger than expected

Tags: sas, proc-report

This code is generating file size greater than 5MB, even though I only have 3200 records. Any suggestions ? help will be much appreciated. I have been struggling with it from past 2 days.

it is giving me insufficient memory error. I have other codes very similar to this one and I am able to run that code without any errors.

```
%macro report(date);

%let a= %eval(%sysfunc(today());
%let Year= %sysfunc(putn(&a,year4.));
%let Mon= %sysfunc(putn(&a,month2.));
%let Day= %sysfunc(putn(&a,day2.));


Proc SQL;

Create table vdata.Report as
Select Country, Province, City, Code, Link, Activity, First_Name, Last_Name, 
Is_Coordinator, Is_Host, email, Phone, Business_Group, Managers_Email, Transportation
from V_Data.raw_plus_&date;

Quit;


Proc Sort data=vdata.PM_Report;
by Country Province Activity Last_Name;
run;


ods listing close;
ods tagsets.EXCELXP file="/path/ Report - &date..XML";
ods tagsets.ExcelXP options (Sheet_name="Report");

proc report data=vdata.Report nowd 
style(header)=[font_weight=bold background=cxDCE6F1 font_size=1.2 ]
;
COLUMN ("Registration as of &Year-&Mon-&Day" ("Report" Country Province City Code Link Activity First_Name Last_Name 
Is_Coordinator Is_Host email Phone Business_Group Managers_Email  Transportation));

DEFINE  Country / Display FORMAT= $char100. Style(column)=[WIDTH=75 font_size=1] style(header)=[background = CXC2D69A]   SPACING=2   LEFT "Country" ;
DEFINE  Province / Display FORMAT= $char100. Style(column)=[WIDTH=60 font_size=1] style(header)=[background = CXC2D69A]  SPACING=2   LEFT "Province";
DEFINE  City / Display FORMAT= $char100. Style(column)=[WIDTH=80 font_size=1]  style(header)=[background = CXC2D69A]   SPACING=2   LEFT "City" ;
DEFINE  Code / Display FORMAT= $char100. Style(column)=[WIDTH=170 font_size=1]  style(header)=[background = CXC2D69A]  SPACING=2   Left "Project ID#" ;
DEFINE  Link / Display FORMAT= $char100. Style(column)=[WIDTH=200 font_size=1] style(header)=[background = CXC2D69A]    SPACING=2   left "Region" ;
DEFINE  Activity / Display FORMAT= $char100. Style(column)=[WIDTH=500 font_size=1]  style(header)=[background = CXC2D69A]  SPACING=2   left "Select an Activity" ;
DEFINE  First_Name / Display FORMAT= $char100. Style(column)=[WIDTH=90 font_size=1]  style(header)=[background = CXC2D69A]  SPACING=2   left "First Name" ;
DEFINE  Last_Name / Display FORMAT= $char100. Style(column)=[WIDTH=220 font_size=1] style(header)=[background = CXC2D69A]   SPACING=2   left "Last Name" ;
DEFINE  Is_Coordinator / Display FORMAT= $char100. Style(column)=[WIDTH=120 font_size=1] style(header)=[background = CXC2D69A]   SPACING=2   left "Activity Coordinator" ;
DEFINE  Is_Host / Display FORMAT= $char100. Style(column)=[WIDTH=80 font_size=1]  style(header)=[background = CXC2D69A]  SPACING=2   left "Host" ;
DEFINE  Email / Display FORMAT= $char100. Style(column)=[WIDTH=250 font_size=1]  style(header)=[background = CXC2D69A]  SPACING=2   left "e-mail" ;
DEFINE  Phone / Display FORMAT= $char100. Style(column)=[WIDTH=100 font_size=1]  style(header)=[background = CXC2D69A]  SPACING=2   left "phone #" ;
DEFINE  Business_Group / Display FORMAT= $char100. Style(column)=[WIDTH=270 font_size=1]  style(header)=[background = CXC2D69A]  SPACING=2   left "Business Group" ;
DEFINE  Managers_Email / Display FORMAT= $char100. Style(column)=[WIDTH=220 font_size=1]  style(header)=[background = CXC2D69A]  SPACING=2   left "Reporting Managers Email" ;
DEFINE  Transportation / Display FORMAT= $char100. Style(column)=[WIDTH=220 font_size=1] style(header)=[background = CXC2D69A]   SPACING=2   left "Transportaion needed?" ;

Compute country;
if country = "Canada" then 
    call define(_row_, 'style', 'style = {background=#FFFFFF FONT_SIZE=1}' );
else if country = "United States" then
    call define(_row_, 'style', 'style = {background=#FFFFFF FONT_SIZE=1}' );
endcomp;


RUN;


ODS ods tagsets.ExcelXP CLOSE;

%Mend;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are more likely to receive assistance if you post the code you've already tried.

Comment: If you've tried very similar code already and it works, you should try and find what is different about this code that makes it fail. We might be able to help you with that bit.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but I'll hazard a guess that it is to do with the width of the fields you are exporting.

Check the width of all of the variables being exported to excel.  They're very wide.  Combined they have a width of about 2500 bytes.

```
Width*Rows = ~2500*3200 = 8,000,000 bytes = 8 megabytes
```

I'm not sure if excel does any compression on consecutive space characters, but if not, then this would easily explain the size.

For any variables that are excessively wide, assign them an appropriate width with the `length` statement.  I'm pretty sure you don't need a width of 100 for a phone number (for example).

Comment: Hi, Yes I did try that. It is still not working. Some times it produces result and most of the times it give me this error "ERROR: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of insufficient memory."